# Where to start to create a product customization website?

Tags: html, web, product

I would like to create a product customization website for T-shirts and I do not know where to start. Could you please recommend any programming languages that I should use or any tutorials, examples etc? Please take into account that I have to use HTML5. Thank you in advance!

Comment: sorry, your question can't really be answered here, as there are no definite answers to it. There are too many variables you should consider (who's the target, how should the customization happen (graphical, survey, just text...), do the information need to be passed on to a manufacturer, what do you already know about (web)programming, how much time do you have, is it homework or "real world"). My advice: take a look at existing (open source) shop software und their plugins. And keep in mind that learning how to create websites (or programming per se) needs quite some time

Comment: It is homework, not 'real-world'. I have created websites before and I have used html, html5, css, javascript, php, c#, java, ajax, jquery but I have never implemented anything similar in the past. The customization includes both graphical and text elements. As for the time, I have about three months to do it and I know that programming needs a lot of time, I just don't know where to start for this project.

Answer (score 0):

I like developing web applications with Python and **Django** it has awesome community and projects around the language and framework.